# Doubt in Scale Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

```
% speckle scale function
Iuniform = imcrop(I,rect);
q0_squared = (std(Iuniform(:))/mean(Iuniform(:)))^2;
```

In the above equation, they are finding `q0_squared` by dividing the `standard deviation` ROI(Region of Interest) in an image by its `mean` value and taking square of the whole image.

What information this provides us? Mathematically, ($\frac {standard deviation}  {Mean})^2$ is defined as what ? In the above equation they are using it as a scaling function. Can anyone explain this and simple?

Comment: It seems at though it is written as $\left(\frac{\text{standard dev}}{\text{mean}}\right)^2$.

Comment: Yes, it is.. Sorry for the mistake.. But what does it mean?

Comment: @ErikMiehling Corrected the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity $\frac{\sigma}{\mu}$ is commonly referred to as the coefficient of variation in statistics and probability theory. It represents how much variability there is compared to the mean. I imagine when this quantity is computed for an image, it gives a measure of the amount of change of detail/color (or some other attribute) is present in the image.